# Sinatra HTTP 'PUT' method

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

Something's wrong with the PUT action here, the form gets processed but the updated field is not being saved.

I've did what Sinatra users are doing, by adding in "_method" for Sinatra to recognise that's its a HTTP PUT action. Could anyone spot any mistake here?

```
# edit
get '/entries/*/:id/edit' do
  @entry = Entries.get(params[:id])
  @title = "edit"
  erb :edit, :layout => :edit_layout
end

# update
put '/entries/:id' do
  @entry = Entries.get(params[:id])
  if @entry.save
    redirect "/entries/id=#{@entry.id}"
  else
    redirect "/enewsletters"
  end
end

<!-- Edit form -->
<form action="/enewsletters/edit/<%= @entry.id %>" method="post">
  <input name="_method" value="put" type="hidden"/>
  <p>
    <label>Content</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="entry[title]" value="<%= @enew.title %>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="update">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing any update to the `@entry`, you're just fetching the specific entry with the id from params. Are you using ActiveRecord? If so, instead of `@entry.save`, try `@entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])`.

Edit: I'm guessing you're not using AR since I just noticed the `.get` call. Whatever ORM you are using must have an easy way to update the attributes and then save the record.

Comment: arrhh..thanks. @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry]) works! I'm using datamapper.

Comment: If that solved your problem, I'd appreciate you marking this as the correct answer for future readers... and for my selfishness of rep ;).